# English History professors are very smart is ambiguity?

Tags: grammaticality, questions

Also, She hates scratching dogs is ambiguous too?

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Can you make sure your title matches your question body - right now they seem to be asking two completely separate things - and elaborate on where you think the ambiguity lies? (As in, list the two separate interpretations you think are possible.)

Comment: @Martha, I think they mean "English history professors are very smart," and "She hates scratching dogs."  If you think about those sentences, they are both ambiguous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, both statements can be interpreted in two ways.

**English** can be understood to modify either **history** or **professors**.

and **scratching** can be understood to refer either to her action or to that of dogs.

To clarify these statements, they can be rewritten as:

> Professors of English history....
>   or
>   British professors of history....
>   or
>   Professors of history in England....
>   or
>   English-speaking professors of history

although the last two raise other concerns.

and

> She hates dogs that scratch
>   or
>   She hates to scratch dogs